# TYPO3 add two additional columns to pages and edit in pages

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Typo3 10.4.16

For my own extension, I would require two additional values, a start and end time.
The idea is to add these two date fields to `pages` and use these values in my extension.
The two columns I have already added to `pages`. But I have problems making these two fields visible in the backend.

```
    <?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') or die(); 

// Feld definieren
$tempColumns = [
    'tx_starttime' => [
//      'displayCond' => 'FIELD:list_type:=:album_showalbum',
        'label' => 'StartTime',
        'exclude' => 0,
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'input',
            'eval' => 'trim',
        ],
    ],
    'tx_endtime' => [
        'label' => 'EndTime',
        'exclude' => 0,
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'input',
            'eval' => 'trim',
        ],
    ],
];

// Feld der allgemeinen Datensatzbeschreibung hinzufügen - noch keine Ausgabe im Backend!
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('pages', $tempColumns);

// Neue Palette dem Tag hinzufügen, nach dem Titel - Dadurch Anzeige im Backend
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
    'pages',
    'tx_starttime', 'tx_endtime'
);
// Feld einer neuen Palette hinzufügen
/*\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addFieldsToPalette(
        'pages',
        'page',
        'tx_starttime, tx_endtime',
        'after:doktype'
        );*/
```

My current understanding is, that additional fields should be added under the "Extended" tab on the page->edit backend view.

I also tried to use `addFieldToPalette` instead of `addToAllTCAtypes`. But in both cases, I cannot see the new fields.
What's wrong with my understanding or my code?

Comment: `addToAllTCAtypes()` has only two parameters: the tablename and the (comma separated) list of fieldnames. In your snippet, the field names are each a parameter.
Yes, your fields should appear in the "Extended" tab. Have you clear your caches?

Comment: Julian, thanks, that was the stupid mistake!

Comment: BTW, pages table contains start and end time fields... since... forever, why do you need to add an additional two?